# Custom FileDialog in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick

I was willing to use FileDialog from QML but it turns out not usable for **SaveAs** situations (because you cannot specify a non-existing file name) and moreover the feel of the dialog is not really modern or mobile.

As a workaround I have decided to build a simple **MyFileDialog** which looks like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Popup
{
    implicitWidth: window.width / 3 * 2
    implicitHeight: window.height / 3 * 2
    x: (window.width - width) / 2
    y: 20
    modal: true
    focus: true

    property alias title: popupLabel.text

    contentItem: ColumnLayout
    {
        id: settingsColumn
        spacing: 20

        // Popup title.
        Label
        {
            id: popupLabel
            font.bold: true
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        }

        // File path.
        TextField
        {
            id: field
            placeholderText: "File path..."
            implicitWidth: parent.width
        }

        // Buttons.
        RowLayout
        {
            spacing: 10

            Button
            {
                id: okButton
                text: "Ok"
                onClicked: { onOkClicked(); close();}

                Material.foreground: Material.primary
                Material.background: "transparent"
                Material.elevation: 0

                Layout.preferredWidth: 0
                Layout.fillWidth: true
            }

            Button
            {
                id: cancelButton
                text: "Cancel"
                onClicked: { state = false; }

                Material.background: "transparent"
                Material.elevation: 0

                Layout.preferredWidth: 0
                Layout.fillWidth: true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I would like this dialog to be reusable for several situations, e.g. to open files, to import files, to save files... But then this means that the behavior of **okButton.onClicked** is different for each of these situations.

I have tried several ways to specify a custom (or say changeable) behavior for **okButton.onClicked** but with no great luck so far. Here is what I have tried:

1. Make a property alias of **okButton.onClicked** in Popup
2. Define **okButton.onClicked** where I use the Popup
3. Define a behavior function outside the Popup and provide it to the Popup

None of these attempts worked and I always have compilation errors.

Any idea of what I could to make my code reusable?

Also I could find no recent and clean example on the internet, any idea of where I could find that?

Thanks,

Antoine.

Comment: Which `FileDialog` are you talking about? [This one can save as.](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-dialogs-filedialog.html#selectExisting-prop)

Comment: @Mitch, you really saved me several hours, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`FileDialog` from the `QtQuick.Dialogs` import has a [`selectExisting`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-dialogs-filedialog.html#selectExisting-prop) property which you can use to save as:

> Whether only existing files or directories can be selected.
>
> By default, this property is true. This property must be set to the desired value before opening the dialog. Setting this property to false implies that the dialog is for naming a file to which to save something, or naming a folder to be created; therefore selectMultiple must be false.

If you want a modern mobile interface, you're better off making your own. I wouldn't go with a dialog, though, as that's more desktop-centric. Dropbox, for example, uses something like a `ListView` in its mobile UI:

[image: dropbox]

Comment: Ha ha! That's exactly the type of advice I was expecting! I will use the dialog for the prototype version but as soon as we hit beta we'll transition to your Listview, Dropbox-like proposition. Thanks!